# Capture functionality on HTML mode, what's missing?

Tags: cordova

Getting acquainted to Phonegap, I stumbled into this error I cannot assess (or can, sort of).

So I want to make an HTML page with a button that allows to capture an image (with the mobile) using the device camera, nothing fancy I suppose.

I took the essential of the code from Phonegap's documentation, and here's what my page looks like :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Capture Image</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="plugin_loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="json2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Called when capture operation is finished
    //
    function captureSuccess(mediaFiles) {
        var i, len;
        for (i = 0, len = mediaFiles.length; i < len; i += 1) {
            uploadFile(mediaFiles[i]);
        }       
    }

    // Called if something bad happens.
    // 
    function captureError(error) {
        var msg = 'An error occurred during capture: ' + error.code;
        navigator.notification.alert(msg, null, 'Uh oh!');
    }

    // A button will call this function
    //
    function captureImage() {
        // Launch device camera application, 
        // allowing user to capture up to 2 images
        navigator.device.capture.captureImage(captureSuccess, captureError, {limit: 2});
    }

    // Upload files to server
    function uploadFile(mediaFile) {
        var ft = new FileTransfer(),
            path = mediaFile.fullPath,
            name = mediaFile.name;

        ft.upload(path,
            "http://my.domain.com/upload.php",
            function(result) {
                console.log('Upload success: ' + result.responseCode);
                console.log(result.bytesSent + ' bytes sent');
            },
            function(error) {
                console.log('Error uploading file ' + path + ': ' + error.code);
            },
            { fileName: name });   
    }

    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onclick="captureImage();">Capture Image</button> <br>
    </body>
</html>
```

Trying it out (on my computer), I get the following errors :

- **XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/toshiba/Desktop/test%20camera/cordova_plugins.json. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.**
- **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'capture' of undefined**

The first error is related to some **cordova_plugins.json** that isn't there, and in fact it isn't. From what I understood : all you need to use phonegap is the the cordova js (which is in my case plugin_loader.js, a bit modified on recommendations I found on internet to help with my problem, which didn't work...).

The second error is related to following line :

```
navigator.device.capture.captureImage(captureSuccess, captureError, {limit: 2});
```

But that is normal I guess on the computer, which is not a device in a "mobile sense".

I've also made the trial on two mobile devices, but failure follows.

I have my JS files, so my question is the following : is it necessary to develop which Phonegap with HTML5 and then compile to some other specific platform native file for the thing to work? I hope not, because I want to work in web-app mode, or is my problem related to some missing files, if so : where can I find the surest functioning cordova js file ?

**Edit** : I also think that on computer, the failure has to do with the navigator from which it cannot retrieve the device specifications and (thus) the camera functionality (?!), that's on computer but it can just be also the case on mobiles (mobile's navigator having the same issue).

I hope you bear with me as I am new to this, and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cleanest answer I found to this problem is not technical, rather "categorical" one : you can't use PhoneGap on HTML5 in the sense you cannot just leave it to HTML. 
What you do is write on HTML5 but build (and you have to build) to some native plateform format (.apk for example).

Otherwise, I found that there are methods you can exploit to handles media capabilities with HTML5, no doubt that takes a bit or developement, but it's still a start.